# Swagger не генерирует requestBody в моём ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Пытаюсь настроить Swagger для своего Web Api.
Настраивал в соответствии с https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio.

```
public partial class MojReisController : ControllerBase
{
    MojReis mr = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Аутентификация пользователя.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Пример запроса:
    ///
    ///     Post /Auth
    ///     {
    ///        "agentCode": "****",
    ///        "password":"****"
    ///     }
    ///
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name = "data">Данные для аутентификации</param>
    /// <response code="200">Возврат аутентификационных данных</response>
    /// <response code="400">Неудачная попытка выполнить метод</response>
    /// <returns>Аутентификационные данные пользователя</returns>
    [HttpPost("Auth")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public Task<MRauthenticateResponse> Post([FromBody] MRauthenticate data)
    {
        return mr.Authentication(data);
    }
```

Тип "MRauthenticate" находится в другом проекте (библиотека классов), на который добавлена ссылка в проекте с Web Api.
пакет Swashbuckle.AspNetCore добавлен к проекту с Web Api.
После запуска проекта вижу следующее:
[image: Сгенерированная документация]

Почему я не вижу параметров и requestBody?
Класс MRauthenticate представляет из себя следующее:

```
public partial class MRauthenticate
{
    public string agentCode;

    public string password;
}
```

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код текстом. Не хочется перепечатывать его с картинки для ответа.

Comment: @aepot добавил текст кода

Comment: попробуйте свойства вместо полей `public string agentCode { get; set; }`

Comment: @aepot это сработало! Благодарю)

Comment: @aepot я пытаюсь найти, как отметить Ваш комментарий в качестве решения моей проблемы, но у меня отсутствует нужная кнопка. Возможно, у меня слишком низкий рейтинг.

Comment: Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы заработала сериализация, в классе данных нужно использовать свойства, а не поля.

```cs
public partial class MRauthenticate
{
    public string agentCode { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }
}
```